# shell script to create empty files with all possible permissions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, file-permissions

How to write a shell script that creates empty files with all possible permissions. File names should be, for example, rwxrw_r__.txt. I know how to do it manually. As an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch task5/rwxrwxrwx.txt | chmod 777 task5/rwxrwxrwx.txt
touch task5/rwxr-xr-x.txt | chmod 755 task5/rwxr-xr-x.txt
touch task5/rwx------.txt | chmod 700 task5/rwx------.txt
touch task5/rw-rw-rw-.txt | chmod 666 task5/rw-rw-rw-.txt
touch task5/rw-r--r--.txt | chmod 644 task5/rw-r--r--.txt
touch task5/rw-------.txt | chmod 600 task5/rw-------.txt
```

I do not know how to write a script that will create files according to the required template and give them permissions

Comment: you seem to be missing 3 permissions

Comment: `a | b` runs both `a` and `b` _at the same time_, with the stdout from `a` connected to the stdin of `b`. You definitely don't want to use it here: Sometimes your `chmod` will try to change the file's permissions before the `touch` finishes creating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a loop:

```
for ((i=0; i < 512; i++)); do 
    mod=$(printf "%03o" "$i"); 
    touch ${mod}.txt; chmod $mod $mod.txt; 
done
```

Rather than trying to construct the names, if you want the names to look like the output of `ls -l`, just do something like

```
for ((i=0; i < 512; i++)); do
    mod=$(printf "%03o" "$i") 
    touch ${mod}.txt
    chmod $mod $mod.txt
    n=$(ls -l $mod.txt | cut -b1-10)
    mv -- $mod.txt "$n.txt"
done
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to name the files appropriately

Comment: thank you for the answer. I will try. Could you explain to me please why ' i < 512', and also  this "%03o\n"

Comment: The `%03o` causes printf to print the value as a 3 digit octal.  This causes the loop to go 000,001,002,...776,777 so that you get all the possible modes (ignoring sticky bit, etc.  To be complete you would need 1000 and 1001 and 2777, etc.). The `\n` is totally unnecessary, since the newline will get stripped.  Will edit to remove.

Comment: Change `mv $mod.txt $n.txt` to `mv $mod.txt ./$n.txt` or `mv -- $mod.txt $n.txt` to avoid `mv` interpreting the dashes as arguments. It is also better to replace `awk '{print $1}'` with `cut -b1-10`, since some file systems have extended attributes and  will show an extra trailing character in the file mode column output of `ls -l`.

Comment: Also, should not the `$i` be incremented until `$i < 4096` to take account of the other permission bits?

Comment: @accdias Yes, strictly i should be higher to account for permissions higher than `777`, but that seems an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @WilliamPursell  thank you for the detailed explanation. I checked the code it works perfectly. the only question that remains is this how did you figure out the number 512?

Comment: 512 is one greater than 0777 You want all permissions between 0 and 777

Comment: @WilliamPursell your solution  is great and I understand the explanation. Thank you so much. But I wonder if there is any other way to solve this problem, not to mention the value of 512?

Comment: The octal expression `1000` is the decimal number 512.  I don't know a better way to iterate over "all possible permissions" other than by iterating over all possible permissions.  As mentioned in other comments, you actually need to consider the setuid bit, the setgid bit, and the sticky bit, so you really need to loop from 0 to 4096 and use a 4 digit specifier.  eg `chmod 0644` and `chmod 7777`, etc.

Comment: @WilliamPursell instead of making use of `ls` you could use `stat --printf "%A"` to extract the permission string.

Comment: @It'sme If you prefer, you could write the loop condition as: `for (( i = 0; i <= 0777; i++ ));` and be a bit more explicit.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you. I found the solution by combining your code and code from Paul. Here it is:
```p=({0..7})
for u in "${p[@]}"; do for g in "${p[@]}"; do for o in "${p[@]}"; do
  f="$u$g$o"; touch "$f".txt
  chmod $f $f.txt
  n=$(ls -l $f.txt | cut -b1-10)
  mv -- $f.txt "$n.txt"
done; done; done ```

Answer (score 3):

It's just a permutations problem.

```
p=( --- --x -w- -wx r-- r-x rw- rwx ) # the set of permissions
for u in "${p[@]}"; do for g in "${p[@]}"; do for o in "${p[@]}"; do
  f="task5/$u$g$o.txt"; touch -- "$f" && chmod "u=${u//-/},g=${g//-/},o=${o//-/}" -- "$f";
done; done; done
```

## NOTE

- thanks to @kvantour for pointing out I was passing dashed to chmod, and that it doesn't know what to do with them. I am surprised I wasn't getting errors.

Let's break it down and look at what's happening.

If you have any questions about what permissions sets mean or how `chmod` works, [see here](https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html).

So for each of the user, group, or other, there are eight possible symbolic representations (representing the values of one octal digit, 0-7).

We set those into a simple array we can loop over.

```
p=( --- --x -w- -wx r-- r-x rw- rwx ) # the set of permissions
```

You can access any element with it's octal digit (technically the decimal equivalent, but that doesn't matter unless you go over 7) so `${p[5]}` is `r-x`. Indexing with `@` returns the whole array, so the loops walk through them sequentially with `${p[@]}`.

To get every possible permutation, we loop over them for each of user/group/other.

```
for u in "${p[@]}"; do # assign each permission set for the user
for g in "${p[@]}"; do # assign each permission set for the group
for o in "${p[@]}"; do # assign each permission set for the other
```

This is just simple iterations in nested loops to hit every permutation.

```
  f="task5/$u$g$o.txt" # assign the permissions string AS the filename
```

By putting the path and filename info into a variable, we can maintain any changes in one place, and it makes the rest of the line shorter and easier to read.

```
  touch -- "$f" && # create the file and test for success
```

`touch` will create an empty file. Because the filenames *could* sometimes begin with a dash (any time the permissions disallow user read), we give `touch` a first argument of `--`, which is a *NIX standard idiom meaning "options are done now, anything left is arguments"; otherwise it would try to interpret a leading dash as an invalid option set and fail. This won't be a problem while you are putting "task5/" at the beginning of the filename, but if you end up using the filename bare it would.

The `&&` is a boolean test to see whether `touch` succeeded. If it did not, then we silently skip trying the `chmod` (`touch` should have emitted an error message for your debugging, but if that fails, you probably got a ton of them, and will need to fix whatever ...)

```
  chmod "u=${u//-/},g=${g//-/},o=${o//-/}" -- "$f" # change the permissions
```

This uses `chmod`'s symbolic mode. We have the permissions of each section from the nexted loops - just apply them. Again, we use the `--` to tell `chmod` when we are done passing options so that leading dashes in filenames won't be a problem later if you refactor just just `cd` into the directory and create the files locally, though even then you could always prefix `./` or `$PWD/` on it.

We have to get rid of thew dashes in the symbolic file modes, though, as (thanks agains @kvantour) `chmod` doesn't recognize those. An inline string edit works beautirully: in `"u=${u//-/},g=${g//-/},o=${o//-/}"`, the `//` inside the variable spec is a replacement of all occurrences, replacing `-` with the *nothing* between the following `/` and `}`.

```
done; done; done # these just close each of the loops
```

We could (and probably should) put each of these on separate lines, but the interpreter doesn't care since we used semicolons. It lets us compact the code to put the loop nesting and closures on lines together, so long as you are comfortable with the ONE thing that's changing being obvious enough.

Anything you still have questions about that I didn't cover?

## Alternate

Another version, because I like going through a loop once instead of nested shenannigans...

```
p=( --- --x -w- -wx r-- r-x rw- rwx ) # the set of permissions
for dec in {0..511}; do oct="$(printf "%03o" "$dec")"
  u="${p[${oct:0:1}]}"; g="${p[${oct:1:1}]}"; o="${p[${oct:2:1}]}";
  f="task5/$u$g$o.txt"; touch "$f"; chmod "u=${u//-/},g=${g//-/},o=${o//-/}" "$f";
done
```

This walks through the combinations numerically, converts decimal to octal with `printf`, slices each digit out of the octal permission set with basic substring parsing and uses it to look up the relevant string from the array, assign the segments, assign the resulting filename, `touch`/create the file, then apply the scrubbed permissions strings with `chmod`. It's once-through and faster, if a little harder to understand.

```
u="${p[${oct:0:1}]}" # grabs 1 byte from offset 0 of $oct as index to $p
```

As suggested, to skip the decimal to octal conversion step, replace:

```
for dec in {0..511}; do oct="$(printf "%03o" "$dec")"
```

with

```
for oct in {0..7}{0..7}{0..7}; do
```

Comment: Also - this feels very much like homework. Do you need me to break that out and explain it in more detail?

Comment: Paul your script works perfectly. Please when you have a chance break it out for me)

Comment: Paul, I had a closer look I got it)

Comment: Great. Accept the solution? And let me know if you want more exposition on something. Make sure you understand it.

Comment: thank you Paul for the solution and the explanation

Comment: Paul, I have just noticed that some file names don't match the permission they have.  The script names the files correctly but there is a problem with permissions. Some of them don't match.  For example:   -r-------- 1 bridge bridge 0 Jul 22 14:43 r----x--x.txt. Could you help me to fix that?

Comment: Are you running on a Windows machine? Things like git bash under windows have limitations...

Comment: Paul, I have Windows OS on my PC but I run the script on a Unix server. I do not use git bash

Comment: Paul, I have Windows OS on my PC but I run the script on a Unix server. I do not use git bash

Comment: While extensivly explained, this cannot work. The command `chmod` does not understand permissions which contain a hyphen. The `chmod` command should read more something like: `chmod "u=${u//-/},g=${g//-/},o=${o//-/}" -- "$f"` where we git rid of all the hyphens.

Comment: @kvantour you are right. now the code works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks, @kvantour. I didn't think of that. Will edit for future reference.

Comment: You're welcome. Furthermore, if you want to avoid the octal conversion, you can do `{0..7}{0..7}{0..7}` instead of `{0..511}`

Comment: Even better! I wanna be you guys when I grow up!

Answer (score 1):

As per Paul Hodges answer - this is a permutation question - .  However, this approach uses bash with SQLite in memory database to generate a data set inspired by this web page, https://towardsdatascience.com/unix-permissions-the-easy-way-98cc19979b3e    creating a cartesian product out of eight records - generating the commands and placing the octal alongside the user group all permission set

The octal for the chmod is illustrated in this approach - which more aligns with the original request

```
#!/bin/bash

WorkingFolder=task5
RunnerFile=_T5Builder.bash
rm -Rf ${WorkingFolder} ${RunnerFile}
mkdir ${WorkingFolder}

sqlite3 << FIN
.headers off
.mode column
.once ${RunnerFile}
with cte_elements as (
select '0' as Id, '000' as Octal, '---' as Permission union
select '1', '001', '--x' union select '2', '010', '-w-' union
select '3', '011', '-wx' union select '4', '100', 'r--' union
select '5', '101', 'r-x' union select '6', '110', 'rw-' union
select '7', '111', 'rwx'
)
, cte_allpermissions as (
select cte_elements.Id || cte_elements1.Id || cte_elements2.Id as Dec
     , cte_elements.Octal || cte_elements1.Octal || cte_elements2.Octal as OctFull
     , cte_elements.Permission || cte_elements1.Permission || cte_elements2.Permission as Permission
 from -- cartesian product 
  cte_elements cross join cte_elements cte_elements1 cross join cte_elements cte_elements2 --cartesian product
)
, cte_constructor as (
select 'touch ${WorkingFolder}/' || Dec || '_' || Permission || '.txt;' as "#TouchCommand"
    ,  'chmod ' || Dec || ' ${WorkingFolder}/' || Dec || '_' || Permission || '.txt   ;' as ChmodCommand
    , 'echo -n "' || Dec || ' "' as  Progress
  from cte_allpermissions
)
select * from cte_constructor;
FIN

chmod +x ${RunnerFile}
echo Top And Tail of Runner File ${RunnerFile}
head -2 ${RunnerFile}
tail -2 ${RunnerFile}

source ${RunnerFile}
echo
echo Done
ls -l ${WorkingFolder} | awk '{print $1, $9}' | more
```

**Output as follows** (takes about 40 seconds - if performance is really an issue

```
MyNode:~/viasql$ time ./CreateAllPermFiles.bash
Top And Tail of Runner File _T5Builder.bash
touch task5/000_---------.txt;  chmod 000 task5/000_---------.txt   ;  echo -n "000 "
touch task5/001_--------x.txt;  chmod 001 task5/001_--------x.txt   ;  echo -n "001 "
touch task5/776_rwxrwxrw-.txt;  chmod 776 task5/776_rwxrwxrw-.txt   ;  echo -n "776 "
touch task5/777_rwxrwxrwx.txt;  chmod 777 task5/777_rwxrwxrwx.txt   ;  echo -n "777 "
000 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 010 011 012 013 014 015 016 017 020 021 022 023 024 025 026 027 030 031 032 033 034 035 036 037 040 041 042 043 044 045 046 047 050 051 052 053 054 055 056 057 060 061 062 063 064 065 066 067 070 071 072 073 074 075 076 ...
```

First few files

```
... 761 762 763 764 765 766 767 770 771 772 773 774 775 776 777
Done
total
---------- 000_---------.txt
---------x 001_--------x.txt
--------w- 002_-------w-.txt
--------wx 003_-------wx.txt
-------r-- 004_------r--.txt
-------r-x 005_------r-x.txt
-------rw- 006_------rw-.txt
-------rwx 007_------rwx.txt
------x--- 010_-----x---.txt
------x--x 011_-----x--x.txt
------x-w- 012_-----x-w-.txt
```